# Error in calling a Python script from a Basic function

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am new in Python and Basic. I am trying to replicate the IMPORTHTML function from Google Sheets in LibreOffice (LO) Calc. In a nutshell, I want to create a GetHtmTable( Url, Table Index) Basic function in Calc which will call a Python script to do the heavy work.

So based on Villeroy's [great example](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=73145&p=329658), I implemented in LO 5.1.6.2. the Basic *SOUNDEX* function which calls the Python script `sheetFunctions.py` to get familiar with the process. My environment is Linux Mint 18, I use Python 3, I imported all kind of libraries such as Uno, PIP etc.. I use `PycharmProjects` as a Python editor.

I see clearly under the LO Calc menu tools->macro->organize macros->python the `sheetFunctions.py` Python script, which indeed is in the folder `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/Scripts/python`.

Whenever, I run the SOUNDEX Basic function I see the following error message:

> BASIC runtime error. An exception occurred  Type:
>   com.sun.star.script.provider.ScriptFrameworkErrorException Message:
>   : an
>   error occurred during file opening
>   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/pythonscript.py:429 in function
>   getModuleByUrl() [lastRead = self.sfa.getDateTimeModified( url )]
>   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/pythonscript.py:993 in function
>   getScript() [mod = self.provCtx.getModuleByUrl( fileUri )]

I tried to debug the SOUNDEX basic function and found out the blocking point is when the program runs `getScript("vnd.sun.star.script:sheetFunctions.py$soundex?language=Python&location=user")`.

I've been trying for days now to overcome this error, unsuccessfully I must confess.

I wonder if I need to bring some extra extensions in the Basic environment or a missing add-in in the Linux/Python one?

I changed the *location=user* by *location=document* and got stuck again. I added recently libreoffice-script-provider-python thanks to the command `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python` but this did not help. I also embedded in the Calc document the Python script but same this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Minor point: The question should say *imported* uno, not *implemented* uno.

Answer (score 2):

The location name does not match.  The standard place for self-written scripts is under the [user directory](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language#OpenOffice.org.27s_user_directory).  This is `location=user`, for example `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python`.

Then there is `location=share`, which refers to the path in your question.  These parameters are described under **Python Script** in the [URI Specification](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Scripting_Framework_URI_Specification).

See also my answer to [this question](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/140787/where-does-libreoffice-expect-user-scripts-pythonjavajavascript-to-be-located-on-ubuntu/).  Be sure to try the APSO extension if you haven't yet.  Especially, APSO helps when using `location=document`, because embedding requires several steps including editing manifest.xml.